# Javascript to validate two text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text boxes.

One text box is min and other text box is max.

I want to make sure that the user enters a greater value in the max text box compared to the min text box.Also the case might be handled if the user enters one text box is about to enter the next text box .How can i do this job effeciently.

Comment: what have you done till now? please show some code. @downvoter: its not a crime not to know. +1 because of your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to assign the value to a variable and test them :

```
function checker(){

var min = document.getElementById("min").value ;

var max = document.getElementById("max").value ;

  if(min > max){

    alert('min is more than max');

  }

}
```

Then add checker to a `onchange` on the inputs:

```
<input type='text' id='min' onchange='checker();' />
<input type='text' id='max' onchange='checker();' />
```

Comment: The checker() function here will not have updated values of the min and max elements.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what I was thinking. as they say Location, location, location.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to store the two text box elements in variables so you can access their values later:

```
var min = document.getElementById('min'),
    max = document.getElementById('max');
```

Then, you'll need a function to validate the two boxes.  This function should not run unless both boxes contain a value (to avoid the case you mentioned where the user hasn't yet filled in both boxes).

```
function validate() {
    if (!min.value || !max.value) {
        return;
    }
    // ... do the validation
}
```

For the actual validation inside the function, you'll need to take the text strings inside the input boxes and [parse for numeric values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).  Once you have the two numbers, you can compare their values and alert the user if there was a problem:

```
function validate() {
    var minValue, maxValue;

    if (!min.value || !max.value) {
        return;
    }

    minValue = parseFloat(min.value);
    maxValue = parseFloat(max.value);

    if (minValue >= maxValue) {
        alert('Min Value must be smaller than Max Value!');
    }
}
```

The last thing to do is decide when to run this function.  You'll probably want it to run when either of the text boxes loses focus (onblur).

```
min.onblur = validate;
max.onblur = validate;
```

For a complete working example, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/SZnTM/3/).

Comment: You probably want to replace those `parseInt`s with `parseFloat`s. What if the user enters in 2.5 in the min field and 2.6 in the max field? It'll throw up because the values are "the same." A jsFiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/SZnTM/2/. Still, +1 for a great explanation!

Comment: @TeslaNick, good call. Not sure why I made the dangerous assumption that we were working with integers.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kYXsU/

The function will be called when the the user leaves the min textbox... If the value of min is larger than max a pop-up will occur. (You don't have to use a pop-up but it's up to you).

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Hey</title>
 </head>
<body>
    <label for="max">Max</label>
    <input id="max" />
     <label for="max">Min</label>
    <input id="min" />
    <body>
 </html>
```

//use Jquery

```
$('#min').blur(function() {
  if ($('#min').val() > $('#max').val())
  {
    alert('Min cannot be bigger than max');
  }
  });
```

Comment: -1, this function will run even if a value hasn't been entered into both boxes, which the OP specifically wants to avoid. Also, there's very little explanation.  What in the world is `onBlur="Cool"` supposed to do?

Comment: I removed the word "cool." Hope I didn't offend you too much Michael. If you feel that you have a better answer than me by all means post it.

Comment: I wasn't offended in the least, I just wasn't sure what was going on in your answer. Honestly, I do think I have a better answer than you, and it's been posted for awhile.

Comment: -1: This function doesn't parse the values into numbers, thus you're left with Javascript's counterintuitive number coercion behaviors for your comparisons. For example, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xcQp5/